# Load test with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, load-testing, google-chrome-headless

We have tried to load test our site with puppeteer which is awesome! but with no success.

We took huge AWS machine(we used **c5.metal**) and still we were unable to run a few hundreds of browsers(~200). We started to get error related to timeout.

**BTW:** In the same moment we have tried from our computer and it worked fine so the website wasn't the problem/

My question is, if someone know a better way to run this with lighter version of something that can help run more browser on AWS machine.

***NOTE***: Our process use nodejs child process so every process run only 5 browsers

Comment: Do you run them in headless mode? Do you open multiple browsers or just multiple pages or tabs?

Comment: Headless mode. I run this on linux OS. I user multiple browsers.. I tried also to use a few pages(5) on every browser but the same result..

Comment: How heavy is the site it navigates to? I don't think one core can run more than a few pages in parallel, especially if the website it navigates on has a lot of JS and large DOM.

Comment: I used 96 cores machine.. The site is not very heavy but it uses websocket and works in real time.. So in order to run 10K browsers i will need ~10K cores(1K Machines)? It doesn't make sense.. Normal computer with 4 cores can run multi browsers and pages easily.. When using headless it should be more because there is no GUI

Comment: On normal computers you usually only display/navigate one page at a time. Did you disable rendering of the page to speed things up? I think there are other tricks you can do to make it faster.

Comment: I've come across problems like this at much smaller scale. You can tell if you have memory resource problems by seeing if you get errors on lines like these: const browser = await puppeteer.launch(); or const page = await browser.newPage(); If you have problems on page.goto() then you've got network resource problems.  Puppeteer is in general not good at reporting failures from system resource shortages.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. 
1. How can i speed things up? The purpose here is just to load all the system with the UI. I don't care if the browsers will not do anything with the css/images.. Just need to use the page logic and to request all resources from UI Server
2. The CPU was very high.. and Memory also but it wasn't the problem.. The problem it took a lot of time for the browser to render the page and the loading was slow..

Answer (score 1):

Disable page rendering - or use Puppeteer Firefox instead of Chrome, it’s literally just a different node module

As for the timeout, I’m gonna presume this is because of chrome’s horrid optimisation - run it in headless mode to not require a GUI.

Honestly I doubt it’s the size of the machine, it could be the fact that chrome is just awful, no matter the cores amount.

Realistically no browser was built to have 96 separate instances open - maybe tabs but not instances.

Try opening a less amount and then do more and more as they succeed.

Comment: Tried.. with no success. Either fire fox or disable requests of images/css and fonts didn't give a lot.. Bottom line i cannot run even 1K.
When having multi tabs sometimes it takes even slower.. I manage to have a balance of something like 10 tabs per browser which gave me the best performance

Comment: Honeslty it could just be a case of  FF/Chrome just being really unoptimised for this stuff :/ - maybe try it with disabling cache also and literally any other settings? It could just be FF or Chrome being really unoptimisied

Comment: If this is the engines itself without the ability to create settings that we help to reduce the footprint(memory, cpu, network) in order to run  a lot in parallel.. We don't have anything to do here.. Hoping Google team to shad a light here